# Bootstrap Affix on bottom scroll glitch (Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, affix

Simple page with 2 level header, where 2nd level sticks to top.

Here is the page skeleton: http://jsbin.com/cimobirimisi/9

If you re-size your browser to around 630px of height and try to scroll down, you should notice scroll glitch. Not a problem in IE9, but Chrome and Firefox seems to be affected.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can offset the `.content` div when the header has the `.affix` class is applied:

```
.header2.affix + .content {
  margin-top: 82px;
}
```

Tested in FF32 and CH37 (Don't have IE9 VM on this PC, sorry)

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/cimobirimisi/15/

---

### Some Background:

The issue is that once the `.affix` class is applied, the `.header2` div inherits  `position: fixed`. This brings the `.header.affix` div out of its place in the DOM causing the `.content` div to immediately snap to the top of the page and be hidden beneath (the now fixed) `.header2` div.